# Run MIPS program in command line without opening QTSPIM

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I want to execute a program purely through terminal without having to open QTSPIM and running the program through the GUI. Is there a way around this? I have been using SPIM for this purpose but it's outdated and has some really annoying bugs that have been fixed in QTSPIM.

The `man` page for QTSPIM shows an `-execute` option but I'm not using a MIPS processor so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: How about qemu instead?

Comment: Apparently `qtspim -file foo.asm` should work on any processor (using asm source, not an executable), but yes strangely `-executed` is documented to only work on a MIPS host CPU.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/spim.1.html

Comment: `-file` option just opens the qtspim with the file in question, rather than actually executing the file like the `-f` option does with spim

Comment: So the man page is wrong, `-file` doesn't also execute?  :/

Comment: [MARS](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/download.htm) supports this. Just run it with the name of an assemly file and MARS will assemble and run it at the command line, e.g. `java -jar Mars4_5.jar foo.s`